# What to do with the [average] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wikis

[average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) is a tag applied to [3 questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/average). It currently has no tag wiki, and the tag excerpt reads

> This challenge is related to average or arithmetic mean.

Currently, this is a very specific tag which is arguably covered by the [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag. However, nothing in the [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) very short [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/statistics/info) explicitly says that it covers averages, and it could be beneficial to have a separate tag for challenges around averages.

"average" does have more than one mathematical meaning however - the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) and [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) are both averages, and there are [many different means](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182460/calculate-the-mean-mean-of-two-numbers) than just the arithmetic mean. The [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) tag could reasonably be expanded to include these as well.

There are 259 questions that mention ["average"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=average+-%5Baverage%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano), 23 that mention ["arithmetic mean"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22arithmetic+mean%22+-%5Baverage%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano) and 391 that mention ["mean"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=mean+-%5Baverage%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano), none of which have the [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) tag. If we decide to keep, or even expand, the tag, it could require some effort to properly find and then retag relevant questions

---

I [brought this up in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58598772#58598772) with no real conclusion. Currently, [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) is a [suggested synonym](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/statistics/synonyms) of [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) \${}^\dagger\$. However, it is still being voted on, so 3 negative votes could reject this (I recommend that no one "jumps the gun" until a decision is made, tag synonyms are enough of a hassle without having to do them twice).

Therefore, of the options below, what should we do with the [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) tag?

- Synonymise it with [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics), and (optionally) remove it from the 3 questions it is currently on,
- Expand its scope, edit its tag wiki and begin applying it to more challenges,

  - What should the expanded scope cover?
- Do nothing and leave the tag as it is, or
- Do something else?

---

<sup>\$\dagger\$ Mostly by mistake - I didn't think I had the required score in [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) to suggest it, and expected to be blocked from suggesting it</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Synonymize with [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

According to Wikipedia, an [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) is "a single number taken as representative of a non-empty list of numbers".

Limiting the scope of [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) to "arithmetic mean" would be way too narrow for a tag. Accepting the broader meaning would make it a branch of [descriptive statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_statistics), namely the [central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency) of univariate data. But even though many challenges involve calculating such a measure, I don't feel like it is used as a *core* part of a challenge that often (so it is actually worth using [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) or even [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)).

I suggest to make [average](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average) a synonym of [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics), and use [statistics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) for challenges whose *core* is about calculating a kind of central tendency.